# Is 'granted that' interchangeable with 'given that'?

Tags: phrase-usage

I'm stuck on the following sentence from a piece I'm proofreading:

'Granted that the Maestro had little faith in amateurs, this choir had been well prepared by their chorus master.'

To me it feels like 'given that' sounds better, but I've been instructed not to make any unnecessary changes.

Is 'granted that' acceptable usage in this context if it can be taken to mean something like 'on the assumption that..'?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: We don't say "granted that."  We say "given that" or "granted." There, though, you would only say "given that."  An example of "granted" being used would be something like, "Granted, this choir was well prepared given that the maestro had spent so little time rehearsing with them."

Comment: Thanks - yes that is exactly what I thought, but then I found an online thesaurus giving 'granted that' as a synonym for 'assuming that' and 'conceding that' among other phrases. If there's a usage that's unusual but acceptable I may have to let it pass even though it really doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Nancy "Granted" is probably "granted that" with the *that* drop as usual.

Comment: It's perfectly logical even if it sounds dated.

Comment: _Given that_ is more natural in this sentence. I'd change it.

Comment: I would replace *granted* with *considering*.

Answer (score 1):

“*Granted (that)*” does **not** mean “*on the assumption that*”.
It means: “I accept, **although reluctantly**, that (the following is true:)”.

The truthfulness of the statement that follows is neither questioned nor assumed. It is accepted as fact.

That’s also the case with “*given (that)*”, but “*given (that)*” does not suggest reluctance.

A good alternative for “*granted (that)*” is “*conceding (that)*” or “*admittedly*”. “To concede” and “to admit” convey the same reluctance.

An alternative for “*given (that)*” is “*considering*”.

•

There is another difference between “*given (that)*” and “*granted (that)*”.

“*Given (that)*” suggests that the following clause is **the cause, or one of the causes**, of the main clause.

> *Given that* the performance day is approaching fast, the choir is rehearsing frequently.

means

> The choir is rehearsing frequently, *because* the performance day is approaching fast.

“*Granted (that)*” does not suggest a causal relationship. In fact, it could mean the opposite.

> *Granted* that the choir members have busy shedules, they are *nevertheless* rehearsing quite frequently. It’s amazing they find the time.

means

> The choir members are rehearsing quite frequently, *despite* having busy shedules.

•

**In your example**

> *Granted that* the Maestro had little faith in amateurs, this choir had been well prepared by their chorus master.

means

> Amateurs generally don’t live up the the Maestro’s expectations. *However* this choir might prove him wrong, thanks to the preparations by their chorus master.

On the other hand

> *Given that* the Maestro had little faith in amateurs, this choir had been well prepared by their chorus master.

means

> The chorus master is aware of the Maestro’s lack of faith in the capabilities of amateurs. To prove the Maestro wrong, the chorus master has prepared the choir well.

That’s not quite the same thing.

Only if you want to convey that chorus master wouldn’t have prepared the choir so well, if it wasn’t for the Maestro’s lack of faith, go ahead and use “*Given (that)*”.

Comment: Can you cite any evidence that *granted that* necessitates *reluctance* ?  That's not a necessary connection this native speaker of BrE recognises.  And it's not evident in some of your own examples, eg *Granted that the choir members have busy shedules, they are nevertheless rehearsing quite frequently.*

Comment: grant, verb, definition 1: to accept the truth or existence of (something) usually reluctantly. Synonyms: acknowledge, admit, agree, allow, concede, confess, fess (up), own (up to). Source: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/grant

Comment: If one’s main position is “The choir is rehearsing frequently”, then having to concede that the choir members have busy shedules, isn’t helpful in supporting that position. Conceding points that make one’s position less likely is usually done with more reluctance than offering supporting evidence.

Comment: And if you want a British dictionary: grant, verb, 2nd definition (accept): to accept that something is true, often before expressing an opposite opinion. Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/grant